# Standardise leading zeroes in an input string

Tags: code-golf

Write a program in the shortest number of **bytes** possible that will parse any string given to it by input, and output that string with any and all numbers padded with leading zeroes to match the largest number's length.

For example:

Input:

```
This 104 is an -8 example of 4.518 a string 50.
```

The generated output should become:

```
This 104 is an -008 example of 004.518 a string 050.
```

Note that any digits after the period are not considered part of the "length" of a number. Numbers are considered any sequence of digits with either 0 or 1 periods in the sequence. Numbers will be delimited with either the string boundary, spaces, commas, or newlines. They can also be followed by a period, but only if the period is then followed by a delimiting character. They can also be preceded with a '-' to indicated negatives.  So something like this:

```
The strings 20.d, 5.3ft and &450^ are not numbers, but 450.2 is.
```

Should output the following:

```
The strings 20.d, 5.3ft and &450^ are not numbers, but 450.2 is.
```

That is to say, no modifications.

String input will be no more than 200 characters, if your program has an upper bound for some reason.

The winning answer will be the answer in the shortest number of bytes in **seven days** from the posting of this question.

#### Test cases

Input:

```
2 40 2
```

Output:

```
02 40 02
```

Explanation: both substrings `2` are bounded on one side by a string boundary and on the other side by  .

---

Input:

```
E.g. 2,2.,2.2,.2,.2., 2 2. 2.2 .2 .2. 2d 2.d 2.2d .2d .2.d 40
```

Output:

```
E.g. 02,02.,02.2,00.2,00.2., 02 02. 02.2 00.2 00.2. 2d 2.d 2.2d .2d .2.d 40
```

Explanation: in the first two groups the first four numbers are followed by a delimiter (`,` or  ) and the final one is followed by a period then a delimiter; in the third group, each sequence is followed by the non-delimiter `d`.

Comment: @MartinBüttner yeah, that's a bit confusing, but basically it means that in "253.47", " 253" isn't a number even though it's followed by a period - it's part of a number. Will reword it when I'm back home.

Comment: @JanDvorak I feel like doing so would kind of defeat the point of the challenge - that's an exercise left to the reader. Happy to provide more examples and clarification though.

Comment: so, there's no number in `257.24ft`? Now that's interesting...

Comment: @SebastianLamerichs note that `253.47` is not a sequence of digits...

Comment: @MartinBüttner I padded "4.518", not "4". Functionally they're the same. Basically, don't treat "4.518" as two separate numbers, despite them being delimited by a period.

Comment: also, your spec (sequence of digits, then period, then not a digit) makes `123` in `123.ft` a number but not in `123ft`

Comment: @JanDvorak That's correct. This challenge is designed to be trickier than it looks. Hopefully it lives up to that.

Comment: @SebastianLamerichs but `253.47` isn't a sequence of digits, and doesn't count as a number under your current spec... Will you fix your spec, or your example?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm going to fix my spec. Unfortunately on my phone right now, though. Give me 20-30mins.

Comment: Edited the requirements to have more clarity, is there more ambiguity there?

Comment: The '-' is present in the examples but not in the spec.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yeah, not sure what happened there. You seem to have caught the post in between two edits as i corrected it.

Comment: So, if I'm reading your rules right: `This sentence ends in the number 50. This sentence does not end in a number 5.0.` (Because `50.` has one period, but `5.0.` has two.) Confirm?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen `5.0.` is not a number, but `5.0` is - the period is delimiting there.

Comment: Well, it wasn't a valid delimiter when I posted that comment. :) Anyway, now that periods *are* allowed as delimiters, which numbers, if any, should a string like `1.2.3.4.5` be considered to contain? Is it `1.2`, `3.4` and `5`, or perhaps `1.2`, `.3`, `.4` and `.5`, or something else?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You can handle that however you like - it's not in spec because none of the test cases include it specifically because it's so ambiguous.

Comment: The spec's still broken. "*Numbers are considered any sequence of digits with either 0 or 1 periods in the sequence*", so in the example `strings 20.d` there is a number `20` with 0 full stops delimited by a leading space and a trailing full stop.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Is that better?

Comment: I will answer that question with a question: do you agree that the test cases I've added are correct? (If so, they need to be completed to cover all the corners of the spec).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I disagree with the first test case, but can't think of the word for the start of a file to list as a delimiter. I figured that it would be logically assumed (and indeed, all answers so far have done so).

Comment: `2.2.,` is the other one which I thought you might disagree with.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't see that case anywhere, but maybe I'm blind.

Comment: That's a "*sequence of digits with either 0 or 1 periods in the sequence*" (`2.2`) "*followed by a period [which] is then followed by a delimiting character*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, it's in the spec, but I don't see it in the examples - or were you referring to the spec in the first place?

Comment: Ah, it's `.2.,`. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ruby, 111 bytes

I hope this catches all the details of the spec

```
puts $*[0].gsub(r=/(?<![^,\s])(-?)(\d+)(?=\.?\d*(?![^,\s]))/){$1+$2.rjust(i.scan(r).map{|m|m[1].size}.max,'0')}
```

It reads the input as the first command line argument and prints the result to STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

## Cobra - 282

```cobra
class P
    def main
        r,s,l,n=RegularExpressions.Regex(r'^[\n,]?-?(\d+).?\d*[\n,]?$'),Console.readLine.split(' '),0,0
        for m in 2,for y,x in s.numbered,if r.isMatch(x),while (n-=n-r.match(x).groups[1].length)<if(n>l,l-=l-n,l),x=s[y]=if(x[0]=='-','-0'+x[1:],'0'+x)
        print s.join(' ')
```

For those of you wishing to test this without installing Cobra, it's rather easily converted into equivalent C# code.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 201 chars

```
s=prompt();j=k=l=0,t={}
for(i in s){s[i]==+s[i]&&s[i]!=" "?j++:(t[i-j]=j,j=0);if(j>k)k=j;}if(j!=0)t[+i+1-j]=j
for(i in s){if(t[i])while(k-t[i]){s=s.slice(0,+i+l)+"0"+s.slice(+i+l);t[i]++;l++;}}alert(s)
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how input is meant to be handled here - without spaces (comma delimiting, for example) it seems to just print "0", and with spaces I can't even work out what it's doing (I got an output of "7" for "45 200" but am somehow unable to replicate that).

Comment: @SebastianLamerichs Guess I have to print the output in the program, forgot that.

Comment: @lazertyuiopl Yeah, there has to be output in some form, I was getting tripped up by JavaScript's insistence on returning a value even when not explicitly told to. Not sure where that 7 came from, though. I can confirm that it works fine for comma-delimited input now.

Comment: Are you sure it works? If I input "2 40 2", I get "02 40 2", not "02 40 02".

Comment: @IngoBürk I just inputted 2 40 2 and got 02 40 02 using Chrome 36 -- test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9znz9u3p/7/)

Comment: @IazertyuiopI On the fiddle it works, but if I copy the code from the answer into the console it doesn't work.

Comment: Well I have no idea why. If you include it between <script></script> in a html page it also works, so I assume it is safe to say it is valid JavaScript. The code on the fiddle is copy pasted from the answer.